# How to trigger a terraform script from a button on my website

Tags: amazon-web-services, button, triggers, gitlab, terraform

My website is a form-based application. You input the necessary information about the device on the website then once you select deploy, it should trigger the software that holds the terraform repository, triggering it to build the device using terraform plan and then apply.

However, I can't figure out what software to use. I planned to use an AWS lambda container however lambdas have a 15 min build cycle and the terraform build could take 25 mins+

I then considered Jenkins however we don't have access at work.

Is there a way to use GitLab? Could I initialize the terraform repo by triggering it from a button on my site? I have been searching for a while and can't see much information on my use case.

Please help if possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS Batch for longer-running jobs:

- No time-limit
- Integrates with all other AWS services
- Can be run serverless

It also supports Launch Templates, so you can create/re-use an AMI that already has Go+Terraform support.

Comment: AWS CodeBuild has all those same things going for it, and it also seems more appropriate to me for this sort of job than AWS Batch.

Comment: @MarkB That sounds like an good solution as well, worthy of it's own answer!